# How to implement security question in ASP.NET MVC for reset password or change password?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database-design

I want to ask security question from user for resetting the password. I am facing issue related database that how to manage these question in db and what is best pattern to ask these question.

I tried it in this way .

`User` table:

```
Id
Name
etc
```

`Question` table:

```
ID
Statement
```

`UsersQuestion` table:

```
Id
UserId
QuestionId 
Ans
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. The question you've asked is too broad, you are basically asking everyone to design a solution for you. You need to ask a specific question and show what you've done so far to get it to work! Good luck!